# Value-retuning method that returns # of elements in an int array

Tags: c#, arrays, return-value

I am practicing for Final Exams and one of the practice questions asks:

Write a value-returning method that returns the number of elements in an integer array, which values are less than 100. Note: The total number of elements in the array is not known, and your function has to determine it itself.

I have tried a few different things but, I am not sure how to get this working perfectly.

Comment: You could use array subscript out of bounds exception to test the upper limit.

Comment: This practice question is a little weird. All .NET arrays know their own length -- it's in the `Length` property...

Comment: Also, given the lack of `sizeof` how exactly are you supposed to "dynamically" determine the length? Access until `IndexOutOfRange` is thrown?

Answer (score 1):

A LINQ implementation, just for fun:

```
static int CountSmallValues(int[] arr) { return arr.Count(x => x < 100); }
```

This works because .NET arrays implement `IEnumerable<T>`, thereby allowing the LINQ `Count` extension method to enumerate every element and count the ones that satisfy the predicate.